# How do I create a signal handler in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to define a signal handler in elisp?  I would like an external process (running on the same box) to indicate to emacs that there is some external state that emacs needs to refresh.

Comment: I know you can handle `sigusr` http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Misc-Events.html#Misc-Events and http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2006-10/msg00332.html but I never tried it myself. There's also a way to listen to DBus signals, but I don't know of a way to, say, handle `sighup` or just any arbitrary signal.

Comment: The documentation for the dbus interface is here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/dbus.html (BTW, @wvxvw: thanks for this interesting info)

Comment: You could also look at the elisp source of `server-eval-at`. That should tell you how to communicate with the emacs-server over tcp/ip without `emacsclient` if you want to avoid it for some reason. But, `emacsclient` is simplier. I have the impression that the tcp/ip interface is somewhat easier than the dbus interface. Maybe, that impression is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to enable `server-mode`, and then to "send the signal" run a shell command like:

```
emacsclient --eval '(my-refresh-foo-bar)'
```

where `my-refresh-foo-bar` is an Elisp function you defined for example in your `~/.emacs`.